# Unbalanced recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relation

> $$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{3}) + T(\frac{2n}{3}) + \sqrt n$$
>
> Use the substitution method to prove $T(n) = O(n)$

What I have so far...

$T(n) \leq C_1n + C_2 \sqrt n-C_3 $

$T(n) \leq \frac{C_1n}{3} -C_3 + \frac{2C_1n}{3}+C_2 \frac{\sqrt {2n}}{3}-C_3 + \sqrt n$

I'm not really sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: You substituted once. What does that help?